# Django REST Framework - Getting params from QueryDict in a PATCH

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I curling a PATCH request like so:

```
curl --request PATCH http://api.mycompant.local:8000/v2/foo/15/bar/93923/?param=True
```

However, when I debug, I am finding that I can only access the value of `param` by using `request.GET`. `request.DATA` is empty. That seems wrong to me.

What am i doing incorrectly here?

Thanks!!

Comment: Why it seems wrong to you? If you are doing PATCH and sending data then obviously it will be present in request.GET. What is wrong about it?

Answer (score 1):

You must post some data:

```
curl --request PATCH http://api.mycompant.local:8000/v2/foo/15/bar/93923/ -d "param=True"
```